# I have an error relating to the use of [org] and trying to compile into an elf format

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, operating-system, nasm, bootloader

I'm developing a very basic OS. I am currently nearly done with creating the boot loader for it. However, when it comes to compiling it together and linking it up - I get an error.

Here is my main boot loader code:

```
;
;
; MiyoOS bootloader
;
;

[org 0x7c00]    ; Let the compiler know that this is to be loaded at 0x7c00

    mov bp, 0x8000      ; Put the base pointer (bp) at 0x8000. 
    mov sp, bp          ; Put the stack pointer (sp) at the same place. 
                        ; Note that as youu add to the stack, it grows downwards

    mov bx, BootMessage     ; Load the boot message into bx for later use
    call print_string16 ; Print the string using my 16 bit print function

    call activateProtectedMode      ; Switch to 32 bit protected mode

    jmp $               ; Hang


%include "GDT.asm"      ; Load the Global Descriptor Table to set how we want
                        ; Protected mode to function

%include "GeneralLibrary.asm"   ; Include our general library

%include "ProtectedMode.asm"    ; Include the 'activateProtectedMode' function


BootMessage db "Bootloader ==> Loaded into 16 bit mode", 0
BootProtected db "Bootloader ==> Landed into 32 bit PM", 0

[bits 32]

begin_protected_mode:
    mov ebx, BootProtected      ; Load boot message into the 32 bit extended 
                                ; version of bx
    call print_string32         ; Call our 32 bit print function

    jmp $                       ; Hang

times 510-($-$$) db 0           ; Pad the loaded boot sector with Zeros until
                                ; it reaches the 510th byte

dw 0xaa55                       ; in the last two bytes, we will have the boot
                                ; signature. This will tell BIOS that it can
                                ; boot with this
```

And here is what I have *attempted* to do when compiling it.

```
Hazims-MacBook-Pro:MiyoOS root# nasm -f elf bootloader.asm
bootloader.asm:7: error: unrecognised directive [org]
```

My goal is to turn every one of my boot files into an elf object file. Then I would like to link them together. I would be very grateful if someone were to help me.

Thank you.

Comment: The `org` directive only applies when you are using the binary `-f bin` format with _NASM_. With _ELF_ it will be up to your linker command line/script to determine the origin point. My recommendation would be to use the GNU Linker (part of binutils) rather than the Darwin linker. If you don't intend to link objects with your bootloader, it may be easier (since you are learning) to use  `-f bin` rather than `-f elf` .

Comment: @MichaelPetch I can't seem to be able to use the GNU linker although i have installed it...

Comment: How and where did you install LD (and the other utilities)?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I used make and make install in my desktop when i downloaded a folder containing the utils

Comment: Make install should have said where it was placing it. Likely somewhere under /usr/local ?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I tried that - it still lead me to the darwin linker

Comment: When running LD are you specifying the full path where it was installed? You either have to specify the full path or you need to place the directory that it installed in on your path before everything else.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks, I'll try that tommorw.